# MariaDB pipped querys not executed

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query, command-line

I experience a strange problem on our 3 node MariaDB cluster (10.2.24). Queries send over the command line are received by the cluster but don't get executed. MySQL does not return any errors or warnings. When I execute the query in a mysql shell all queries are executed without any problem.

Bash example (not working)

```
# mysql -uUSER -p -hDBSERVER -e "UPDATE table SET field='test' WHERE status='test';" database

or

echo "UPDATE table SET field='test' WHERE status='test';" | mysql -uUSER -p -hDBSERVER database
```

Result

```
 # mysql -uUSER -p -hDBSERVER -e "SELECT field FROM table WHERE status='test';" database

 +---------------+
 | field         |
 +---------------+
 | production    |
 +---------------+
```

MySQL cli example (working)

```
mysql> UPDATE table SET field='test' WHERE status='test';

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Result

```
mysql> SELECT database.field FROM table WHERE status='test';

+---------------+
| field         |
+---------------+
| test          |
+---------------+
```

lsb_release

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

uname

```
4.4.0-148-generic
```

MySQL version

```
mysql --version
Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.24-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

Does anybody know what's going on here or how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately there are not errors or warnings in the log files. It was the first thing i checked.

Comment: General_log is enabled. I dont see anything in it besided the connection itself. In the slow_query log i can see 1 affected row. So i can say for sure that the correct sql server is responding.

Comment: Your second bash test created a file named `mysql`.  That is not what you wanted.  For that case, use `|` (pipe to), not `>` (send stdout to file).

Comment: ah sorry that was a misstake by me. i use a pipe there and the problem is still the same. i changed my question above.

Comment: What is the setting for `autocommit`?